# How to auto layout two buttons with equal widths in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, autolayout, ios-autolayout

**addConstraintsWithFormat is my custom extension. It works well. But I am having the problem with laying out two buttons horizontally** 
Login Button and register button will be 16 from the bottom and should be equal widths with some space between them

```
func setupViews() {
        [loginButton, registerButton].forEach() { view.addSubview($0) }

        //Constraints
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0]-20-[v1]-16-|", views: loginButton, registerButton)

        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0]-16-|", views: loginButton)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0]-16-|", views: registerButton)


    }
```

Comment: This should be the format for horizontal constraint to have both button to be of equal width "H:|-16-[v0]-20-[v1(=v0)]-16-|"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its [v1(==v0)]